# jq: grab specific repeating key-value from first N elements

Tags: json, jq, key-value, weather-api

I am trying to parse https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/PHI/47,91/forecast/hourly, with mild success.

```
{
  "number": 1,
  "name": "",
  "startTime": "2020-12-16T13:00:00-05:00",
  "endTime": "2020-12-16T14:00:00-05:00",
  "isDaytime": true,
  "temperature": 30,
  "temperatureUnit": "F",
  "temperatureTrend": null,
  "windSpeed": "15 mph",
  "windDirection": "NE",
  "icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/snow,40?size=small",
  "shortForecast": "Chance Light Snow",
  "detailedForecast": ""
}
```

I started with `jq '.properties.periods[0]'` to grab the first element, worked with `jq '.properties.periods[0].shortForecast'` and I figured out that `jq '.properties.periods[0,1,2,3]'` gets me the first 4 elements in the array.

However, I run into a syntax error if I try `jq '.properties.periods[:3]'`

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '['

which I thought would be a shorthand for 0-3.

Additionally, I only want (the same, repeating) specific K/V pairs from each element (eg: `shortForecast`, `temperature`, etc.), but I have not been able to figure out how to combine it all into one `jq` statement.

So how do I grab specific values from the first X elements of an array?  (*I dont really need the keys, just the values.*)

Bonus: would be great to have all values from each element on a single line.

Sample:

```
"2020-12-16T14:00:00-05:00" 30 "Chance Light Snow"
"2020-12-16T15:00:00-05:00" 30 "Snow"
"2020-12-16T16:00:00-05:00" 29 "Heavy Snow"
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the syntax error with JQ 1.6.

Comment: Im running: jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe

Comment: Oh, I see where my syntax error is: the extra period between periods and [:3] in .properties.periods.[:3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.properties.periods[:3]` evaluates to an array of the three items, whereas `.properties.periods[0,1,2]` produces an itemization.  So the abbreviation of the latter would be:

```
.properties.periods[:3][]
```

### Selection

There are numerous possibilities, e.g. to get a specific set of key-value pairs on a single line:

```
jq -c '.properties.periods[:3][]
       | {shortForecast, temperature}' input.json
```

To select just the values as CSV:

```
.properties.periods[:3][]
| {shortForecast, temperature}
| [.[]]
| @csv
```

You might like to use `@tsv` instead, or `join(" ")`, or ....

### Bonus

To get all the values in the order in which they are given, you could simply omit the selection line: `| {....}`

However, that would not be so robust.  The following would be safer:

```
.properties.periods[:3]
| (.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys
| .[]
| [.[$keys[]]]
| @tsv
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the explanation.  This gives me some options to mess around with!